# Can I make push notifications for some email addresses only and not others on my iphone?

Tags: iphone, email, apns

I have one email address i use to sign up for random stuff. and One that I only give out to people i trust. Over the years the one i use to sign up for stuff has gotten riddled with spam. the other one has all my important emails.

I would like to get push notifications from the important email address and not from the one with all the spam.

In the iphone settings it seems like you can only turn this on or off for all email addresses at once.

Is there any way to turn on push notifications for only certain inboxes and not others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

> Settings > Mails, ... > Fetch New Data > Advanced

From there, you can chose how to get new email from each account.

It could be push, fetch (every X minutes) or manual (only when you open the app)

Comment: ok you are right thanks... But in trying to do so i realized the other problem was that i was using gmail accounts which i was surprised to find out, don't support Push notifications directly.

looking online I found a tutorial on how to get push notifications if you use gmail here is the link.

http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740

Answer (score 0):

iOS 12.4 the path is now

```
Settings => 
    Passwords & Accounts => 
        Fetch New Data => 
            Pick a mail account => 
                Pick fetch, push, manual
```